# Wordpress private posts

Tags: wordpress, private, private-members, posts

Ok this must be easy I just can't work out why nothing is working.

I have a wordpress theme with 3 custom post types. I want to restrict access to the majority of the posts and allow an admin to make some post viewable by the public. I want it to be as simple as possible.

What I currently have is, I've set all post to default to private, then the admin can come in and make whichever post he likes to "public" so people that are not logged in can see them.

The problem is with this is I cant get the private posts to show on the fontend for logged in users. I have tried numerous plugins, Members, Advance Member Access and Role Scooper but none of these seem to work as soon as I add custom post types.

Please help guys does anyone know how I can set it so if user logged in show everything including public and private posts and not show private post to non logged in users.

Or is there a better way to handle the private post stuff?

thanks

Comment: I currently using <?php  if (is_user_logged_in() ) { //only logged in user can see this ?>query_posts( 'post_status' => array( 'private', 'publish' ) )<?php } else { ?>query_posts( 'post_status' => array('publish' ) )<?php } ?> does anyone see this as a issue? anything wrong with doing this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make users with 'Subscriber' role, access private posts by adding following code to functions.php.

```
$subrole = get_role( 'subscriber' );
// For private pages
$subrole->add_cap( 'read_private_pages' );
/// For private posts
$subrole->add_cap( 'read_private_posts' );
```

Comment: Yes they can access them but they still dont show up on the front end loops. also how would I use the above code for authors? thanks for your help

Comment: You mean edit permission ? try $subrole->add_cap( 'edit_private_posts' ). But am not sure.

Comment: Sorry no, I just need private post to show on the front end for all logged in users